# get delimiter index

Tags: shell-script

I would like to get delimiter index explain as below.

```bash
t="name,address,gender,phone"
```

the delimiter will be comma and I want to search address in the string and it can return 2.

Comment: What shell are you using? `bash`, `zsh` or any other

Comment: I'm using bash.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Using `bash` you should assign the string `"name,address,gender,phone"` to an array. And you also will have to create a function to get the index of any string.

**Assign string to array:**

```bash
readarray -t array <<< "$(tr ',' $'\n' <<< 'name,address,gender,phone')"
```

**Function to get the index:**

```bash
getIndexOf () {

   local index
   index=-1

   for (( i = 0; i < "${#array[@]}"; i++ )); do
      
      if [[ $1 = ${array[$i]} ]];then
     index=$[ i + 1]
     break
      fi
   done

   echo $index
}
```

*You must be careful with the array variable name. In the function getIndexOf the array variable is called 'array' so when you use 'read -r -a array' the variable must be called 'array' too.*

**Use of getIndexOf function:**

If you want to get the index of `address` then you should use the following:

```bash
getIndexOf address
#Output:
2
```

If you specify a non-existing value then you will get `-1`:

```bash
getIndexOf fuzz
#Output:
-1
```

**Note:** This function only works for unique items. So if you have the array:
`"name,address,gender,phone,name"`, as you can see, you have twice `name`. Therefore in this case, the function will return the first item index that it would be: `1`.

---

**Solution 2**

You can use `grep -n` to get the indexes of some item. First, as the code above you should assign the string to an array:

```bash
readarray -t array <<< "$(tr ',' $'\n' <<< 'name,address,gender,phone,Some name,phone'  )"
```

And now with `printf` and `grep -n` I will get the indexes of any value:

**Getting 'name' index:**

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -n "^name$"
#Output
1:name
```

**Getting 'Some name' index:**

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -n "^Some name$"
#Output:
5:Some name
```

**Getting 'phone' index:**

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -n "^phone$"
#Output
4:phone
6:phone
```

If you only want to get the index and not the matched string (4:phone) you should use `cut -d : -f1` at the end of the pipe:

```bash
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | grep -n "^phone$" | cut -d : -f1
#Output
4
6
```

**Notes:**

1. If you search for a non-existing string you will not get `-1`. Instead, you will get nothing as output.
2. Make sure every word you search with `grep` contains `^` at the beginning of the string  and `$` at the end of this one: `"^word to search$"`

Comment: Thanks Edgar. It works.

Comment: @MinosLiao you're welcome. Could you mark this answer as accepted? It should be useful for me and the site if you do it. [How to mark an answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)